# How does split and strip function work together in python?

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, scientific-computing

```
headers = table.by_tag('th') 
labels = [str(t.content).split('(')[0].strip() for t in headers[3:-1]]
```

I know what is meant by `split()` and `strip()`. But what does `split('(')[0]` means? `headers` is a content from a table.

Comment: `split()` returns a list, so it gives you the first value (the first substring until the first `(` sign)

Comment: @user3322273 The str(t.content) returns these : Jerry Brown (D), Meg Whitman(D)

Answer (score 0):

For example.  HTML was..

```html
<table>
  <tr><th>Jerry Brown (D)</th><th>Meg Whitman(D)</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

headers may be extracted by BeautifulSoup

and result is a list contains below

`["<th>Jerry Brown (D)</th>", "<th>Meg Whitman(D)</th>"]`

so `t.content` is `Jerry Brown (D)` and `Meg Whitman(D)`

```
"Jerry Brown (D)".split('(') = ["Jerry Brown ", "D)"]
"Meg Whitman(D)".split('(') = ["Meg Whitman", "D)"]
["Jerry Brown ", "D)"][0] = "Jerry Brown "
["Meg Whitman", "D)"][0] = "Meg Whitman"
```

and strip() may remove whitespace on both sides of string so...

labels means `["Jerry Brown","Meg Whitman"]`